# транслировать в Java 8 stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Есть вот такой метод

```js
public static List<Pair<String, String>> getCityAssignedCodeForProvider(Set<String> departureAssignedCodes, Set<String> arrivalAssignedCodes) {
        List<Pair<String, String>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String departure : departureAssignedCodes) {
            String[] splitDeparture = departure.split(",");
            for (String arrival : arrivalAssignedCodes) {
                    String[] splitArrival = arrival.split(",");
                    for (String departureSplitItem : splitDeparture) {
                        for (String arrivalSplitItem : splitArrival) {
                            pairList.add(new Pair<>(departureSplitItem, arrivalSplitItem));
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        return pairList;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста преобразовать в lambda expression

Comment: А что вы пробовали? и зачем? код то рабочий

Comment: с использованием stream, наверное, а не лямбды. По условию, у вас есть два набора строк, внутри которых есть какие-то коды, разделенные запятыми, нужно вернуть все пары кодов?

Comment: да нужно верно вернуть каждый с каждым. Но в строке может быть как 1 код(без запятой) так и 2 и 3 и 10 кодов через запятую. Потому каждый с каждым

Answer (score 1):

Наверно уже поздно, но ради интереса сделал:

```
       public static List<Pair<String, String>> getCityAssignedCodeForProvider(Set<String> departureAssignedCodes,
                                                                        Set<String> arrivalAssignedCodes) {
    return departureAssignedCodes
        .stream()
        .flatMap(dString -> Arrays.stream(dString.split(",")))
        .map( dCode -> arrivalAssignedCodes
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(aString -> Arrays.stream(aString.split(",")))
                        .map(aCode -> new Pair<>(dCode, aCode))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: можно вместо `.map( dCode -> arrivalAssignedCodes` использовать сразу `flatMap` и избавиться от `collect`